# 2dsphere compound query performance slow?

Tags: mongodb

I've read the docs but It does not work as expected. I have 64 million of these documents all with different "millisecos":

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5396e85c12f43f5d1bafbd13"),
    "author" : ObjectId("5396ca2b0fe95cf96599d881"),
    "location" : {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            12.52891929999998, 
            16.620259
        ]
    },
    "name": "Jordan", 
    "description" : "aDescription"
}
```

And I have the following 3 indexes in Mongo:

```
{
    // index on the _id
    "location" : "2dsphere",
    // compound index on location and time_1
}
```

How do I quickly query on the compound index to get distinct "names"? My query to get all applicable documents is this:

```
db.mycollection.find({"location":{"$geoWithin": {"$centerSphere": [-83.3434343,24.34343], 0.5}}, "millisecos": {"$gt": 1399522511000, "$lt":1399526111000}})
```

I am not sure how to get to the unique "names" of authors I want.

Is is slow, is indexing supposed to help? How do I make it fast? (w/o sharding). If query is bad, I am open to other recommendations. Does limit help or skip?

Query Plan:

```
{
"cursor": "S2Cursor",
"isMultiKey": true,
"n": 70394,
"nscannedObjects": 70394,
"nscanned": 10479843,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans":70394
"scanAndOrder": false,
"nYields": 141,
"millis": 175250,
"indexBounds": { },
"nscanned": 10479843,
"matchTested": NumberLong(10024353),
"geoTested": NumberLong(60348),
"cellsInCover": NumberLong(26),
"server": mongo-cluster.excelmicro:27017
}
```

Comment: What's "slow"? You have 64 million. How fast do you want it to be? Have you tried putting some cache in front of the db? Like Redis? Or memcached?

Comment: Also, have you checked the query plan? Post the results.

Comment: I want it to be fast on the order of (within/under a minute). I have not put any cache in front of the db. Doesn't redis just make "queries after the first query" faster? My cluster is comprised of 2 machines. Query plan added. If mongo is bad for this, I can accept that.. if there are better alternatives. I was under the impression mongo is great for geospatial search of big data...